Divs eventlistner and Toggle
Please I am having issues with my code, I have 4 div which are flexed and I also have a read more button in each of the div and a P in each div that do not display until the button is clicked my problem is when I click on one of the button the other div listens to the click and toggle while still hiding the details, how do I make each div listen to the click of the button attach to it?
I have tried rewriting my codes but it's still giving same reaction here is my JavaScript code
const learnMoreBtn=               document.querySelectorAll(".showMore");
learnMoreBtn.forEach((button) => {button.addEventListener('click',  () => {const divContainer= this.parentElement;
const details=divContainer.querySelector('.serviceDetails');
details.classList.toggle('active');
if (button.innerText ==='Read More'){

button.innerText='Show Less';
}
else{
button.innerText='Read    More';
}});

});
